# Excel VBA Listbox Requires 2 clicks to select first item - sometimes

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

I am having a strange problem (not critical, just annoying) with an excel VBA form using a Listbox.

My form contains 2 Listboxes along with several other controls.
Selecting a item in listbox2 requires 2 clicks but only for the first item i select in that listbox - subsequent selections are successful with 1 click.  Listbox1 does not exhibit this behaviour.

This problem happens every other time i make any change to the code (even just adding a blank line) and save the excel file containing the code. So I can always get rid of the problem when it occurs by just opening the workbook, adding a blank line to the code anywhere and saving the workbook.

But any idea what is causing this?

Thank You,
Mike

Comment: Is it a case of ListBox1 having the focus.  First click on listbox1 selects the list box, second click selects an item in the listbox.